# Using CSW for GeoServer PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, csw

I am quite new to GeoServer and general OGC fundamentals. I have GeoServer set up and I set up a PostGIS data store which links to a database

I have already been able to make successive calls using WFS to extract data from here. I am looking at other service capabilities offered, like CSW.

I cannot really grasp how it works though. Can someone tell me how I can get records from my database? (using HTTP GET requests)

I can do a GET that returns all the layers I have set up:

```
http://{host}:{port}/geoserver/csw?service=csw&version=2.0.2&request=GetDomain&propertyName=Title
```

But using the GetRecords or GetRecordById returns nothing to do with my data in the database though..

Can someone demonstrate a simple REST call to retrieve a record from the PostGIS database?

Comment: What does it return? It should be metadata

Comment: It returns all my layers (just the names of them)..